# Drop column and line in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Having a pivot table as below:

[image: imgg]

is it possible that i can drop a column and row? I need to drop the column and line 'C'?

Is it possible that i can drop the None value? None is a <class 'NoneType'>

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
np.random.seed(1609)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,4)), 
                  index=list('ABCD'), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
A  5  3  6  9
B  5  4  0  4
C  0  7  5  9
D  0  6  3  3

df = df.drop(index='C', columns='C')

print (df)
   A  B  D
A  5  3  9
B  5  4  4
D  0  6  3
```

EDIT: If `None` is `Nonetype` for me working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), 
                  index=list('ABCD') + [None], 
                  columns=list('ABCD') + [None])
print (df)
     A  B  C  D  NaN
A    5  3  6  9    5
B    4  0  4  0    7
C    5  9  0  6    3
D    3  0  0  8    4
NaN  3  5  3  3    1

df = df.drop(index=[None], columns=[None])

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
A  5  3  6  9
B  4  0  4  0
C  5  9  0  6
D  3  0  0  8
```